# How to get SIP Registration from TekSIPManager?

Tags: android, sip

I installed TekSIP on my windows 7 successfully.

When I run TekSIPManager I can't get the Service started Successfully. I am getting errors in Application Log file.

These are the errors i am getting:

```
could not start any of TekSIP threads:existing..

unable to initialize UDP thread[127.0.0.1:5060]
```

can anybody explain me why am getting these errors.
I set Accounting enabled property true.
I installed TekSipRouter Service, tekRadius also.

Thanks in advance....